# javascript var/let

Tags: javascript

я недавно начал изучать джс.
и вот возник такой вопрос.

задача 
Переменная lang может принимать 2 значения: 'ru' 'en'. Если она имеет значение 'ru', то в переменную arr запишем массив дней недели на русском языке, а если имеет значение 'en' – то на английском. Решите задачу через 2 if, через switch-case и через многомерный массив без ифов и switch.

Решение:

Решение через 2 if:

```
var lang = 'ru';
if (lang == 'ru') {
    var arr = ['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс'];
}
if (lang == 'en') {
    arr = ['mn', 'ts', 'wd', 'th', 'fr', 'st', 'sn'];
}
alert(arr);
```

нашел ответ в инете, но с var а вот с let не знаю как решить. хэлп
если пойму как сделать через иф, то понятно будет как сделать через свитч, а через массив уже сделал.

Comment: Я думаю просто инициализируй пустой массив до if. let arr = []

Comment: тогда alert на if вообще внимание не обращает и выводит пустой массив(

Comment: `let` имеет блочную область видимости, снаружи . `if` переменной не будет видно

Answer (score 1):

`let` "забывается" вне текущих `{скобок}`, поэтому его надо объявлять заранее, если он позже будет нужен в коде:

```js
var lang = 'ru';
let arr;

if (lang == 'ru') {
  arr = ['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс'];
} else if (lang == 'en') { 
  // с else, второе условие не будет лишний раз проверяться, если первое выполнилось
  arr = ['mn', 'ts', 'wd', 'th', 'fr', 'st', 'sn'];
}

console.log(arr);
```

Это можно решить еще с помощью объекта:

```js
let lang = 'ru';

let obj = {
  ru: ['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс'],
  en: ['mn', 'ts', 'wd', 'th', 'fr', 'st', 'sn'],
}

let arr = obj[ lang ];

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь!